# Laplace transform using integrals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have $g(t)=\int_{0}^t f(\tau) d\tau$.

How would I show that $Lg(s)$=$1 \over s$ $Lf(s)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, $g' = f$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Now what can you say about the Laplace transform of $g'$ and the Laplace transform of $g$?

Comment: If you don't know about the relationship between the Laplace transform of $g$ and $g'$, then have a look at this MIT lecture by the ever amiable Arthur Mattuck:
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-20-derivative-formulas/